# WPF Styles based on parent styles

Tags: wpf, xaml

Suppose I have a WPF style for a container element such as a grid which applies styles to its child items automatically, like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Grid" x:Key="FormStyle">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50"/>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

How can I then override certian elements of that style within the grid itself?  For example suppose I wanted one grid to have FormStyle but also have a blue label, like this (which doesnt work):

```
<!-- this works fine and Label size = 50 -->
<Grid Style="{StaticResource FormStyle}">
    <Label Content="Blah"/>
</Grid>

<!-- But this doesnt, label is blue, but normal font size -->
<Grid Style="{StaticResource FormStyle}">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Label Content="Blah"/>
</Grid>
```

I am expecting the `BasedOn={StaticResource {x:Type Label}}` to refer to the current active style for Labels at the current scope - i.e. the label style within FormStyle.  But it clearly doesnt and refers to the base outer label style.

If I do for instance this globally

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50"/>
</Style>
```

Then it is all fine.

I could of course just name the styles, but surly there must be an easier/less verbose way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the lookup process for Static Resources:

1. The lookup process checks for the requested key within the resource
   dictionary defined by the element that sets the property.
2. The lookup process then traverses the logical tree upward to the
   parent element and its resource dictionary. This process continues
   until the root element is reached.
3. App resources are checked. App resources are those resources within
   the resource dictionary that is defined by the Application object
   for your WPF app.

In your case to resolve `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}"` WPF first looks in the `ResourceDictionary` defined inside of `Grid`, then in `Window` - the logical parent of the Grid - and it's `Resources`, and then finally in Application level resources. WPF will not find it anywhere - and defaults to the base style - due to the style being a nested style in `FormStyle`.

Read further about Static Resource Lookup Behavior on [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/fundamentals/xaml-resources-define#static-resource-lookup-behavior).

To get the desired output, you could:

1) Move your `Label` style out of `FormStyle` and in to `Window.Resoruces`

2) Merge the Label style from `FormStyle` into the Label style defined in the `Grid` element.

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource FormStyle}">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Label Content="Blah"/>
</Grid>
```

3) Change your `FormStyle` not to have a nested style for `Label`, but to have setters for Label properties.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Grid" x:Key="FormStyle">
        <Setter Property="Label.FontSize" Value="50"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks very much very helpful.  Moving to Window/Grid sort of defeats the point as its intended to be an app level style used by several windows/controls (I failed to mention that in question).  Point 3 is great